# Disable button unless bot selectors have value

Tags: jquery

OK, I have two HTML select elements and a button. I need to disable the button unless **both** of the selectors have any but default (na) values.

I've got this so far, but it doesn't really work. What am I missing?

**JS**

```
function toggleBtn() {
    if($(".mySelect").val() == "na") {
        $(this).parents("td").find("input:button").attr("disabled", "disabled");    
    } else {
        $(this).parents("td").find("input:button").attr("disabled", "");    
    }
});

toggleBtn();

$(".mySelect").change(toggleBtn());
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="mySelect">
      <option value="na"></option>
      <option value="1">value 1</option>
      <option value="2">value 2</option>
    </select> 

    <select class="mySelect">
      <option value="na"></option>
      <option value="3">value 3</option>
      <option value="4">value 4</option>
    </select> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="click me">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris beat me to it darnit my version is this one

Loop through all your selects, if you find one that's not 'na', disable your select button and stop the loop.  You need to stop the loop or the last element basically dictates how your button behaves.

```
function toggleBtn() {
     var inputButton =  $('input[type="button"]').first();   
     inputButton.attr('disabled', null);
     $(".mySelect").each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).val() != 'na') {
            inputButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            return false
            }
    });
 }
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    toggleBtn();
    $(".mySelect").change(toggleBtn);
    });
```

Plug that in to your script header and see what happens.  This seems to work cross browser and we're using attr...

Comment: OK, this looks great. I use older version of jQuery (1.4.4) so I guess I'll use attr instead of prop. What is my there's a value already in the selectors on page load? Would this still work the same or do i need to add ELSE?

Comment: Yes it will although doesn't look like it's working in IE, lemme see if I can fix that

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you understand that `$('.mySelect')` is a collection of multiple `<select>`s, so calling `.val()` on it returns only the value of the first in the collection. Something like this should work for you:

```
var selects = $('.myChange');
var button = $('table td input:button');

selects.change(function() {

    var defaultVal = true;

    selects.each(function(index, el) {
        if ($(el).val() == 'na') defaultVal = true;
    });

    button.attr('disabled', defaultVal ? 'disabled' : '');

});
```

Any time one of the `<select>`s is changed, we are looping through all of them to see if any has an 'na' value and, if so, we disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(obj).attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: No. If you're going to use a boolean value, use `.prop`. [See why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: but take notice that .prop is only available from jquery 1.6+

Comment: I use jQuery 1.4.4 and in this project cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the id of button. just assign some id to the button and enable and disable based on id.

```
var buttons = $('#button1,#button2,#button3');
buttons.click(function(){
  buttons.(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of it but I have different tabs with similar cases, so I want a one solution for all.

Comment: Ok so use the class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

How about this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YmAc4/)**?

jQuery:

```
function toggleBtn() {
    if ($(".mySelect:eq(0)").val() == "na" || $(".mySelect:eq(1)").val() == "na") {
        $('input[type="button"]').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('input[type="button"]').attr("disabled", false);
    }
};
$(".mySelect").change(function() {
    toggleBtn();
});
toggleBtn();​
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="mySelect">
      <option value="na"></option>
      <option value="1">value 1</option>
      <option value="2">value 2</option>
    </select>

    <select class="mySelect">
      <option value="na"></option>
      <option value="3">value 3</option>
      <option value="4">value 4</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="button" value="click me" disabled="disabled">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(".mySelect").change(function () {
    var buttonstate = 0;
    $('.mySelect').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != 'na') {
            buttonstate++;
        }
    });
    if (buttonstate == 2) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input:button').attr("disabled", "");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input:button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

You can test this here: http://jsfiddle.net/tF8xc/13/